# Edittext doesn't work if it is in headerview of StickyGridHeaders library

Tags: android

I wanted to search header view which is stick to top when user scroll down.

so I used StickyGridHeaders Library(Because I wanted to show item with GridView).

When I put EditText into HeaderView of StickyGridHeadersGridView, EditText doesn't work

There are follow problems;

1. cursor doesn't blink and cursor just stop
2. when i typed soft keyboard, soft keyboard didn't react(i coudln't see clicked animation like darker background)
3. EditText doesn't show word I typed, but there is word in it. it just doesn't appear.(I checked using textwatcher)

What's the problem???

And what I have to do for making sticky search header view?